# running Add-mailboxpermission from aspx page with impersonation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to execute Add-Mailboxpermission from a ASPX page with impersonation of a specific user. an application error from MSExchange Common source is logged in the Event viewer of the web server.

> Watson report about to be sent to dw20.exe for process id: 2992, with parameters: E12, c-buddy-RTL-AMD64, 08.03.0083.006, w3wp, M.E.D.Directory, M.E.D.D.ConnectionPoolManager.BlockImpersonatedCallers, M.E.Common.FailFastException, c84f, 08.03.0213.000.  ErrorReportingEnabled: False

The same code for executing a different Exchange CMDlets including the impersonation call is used and completes without any error.

```
    String ErrorText = "";
    RunspaceConfiguration config = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
    PSSnapInException warning;
    sDecryptedPwd = SecurityManager.Decrypt(AdminPassword, true);

  using (new Impersonator(AdminUserName, "domain name", sDecryptedPwd))
    {
        // Load Exchange PowerShell snap-in.
        config.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin", out warning);
        if (warning != null)
            throw warning;

        using (Runspace thisRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(config))
        {
            try
            {
                thisRunspace.Open();
                using (Pipeline thisPipeline = thisRunspace.CreatePipeline())
                {
                    //Please change parameter values.
                    thisPipeline.Commands.Add("Add-MailboxPermission");
                    thisPipeline.Commands[0].Parameters.Add("Identity", sMailboxName);
                    thisPipeline.Commands[0].Parameters.Add("User", sUserName);
                    thisPipeline.Commands[0].Parameters.Add("AccessRights", sAccessRights);
                    thisPipeline.Commands[0].Parameters.Add("DomainController", sDomainController);

                    iLogManager.Info("Identity: " + sMailboxName + " User: " + sUserName + " AccessRights: " + sAccessRights + " DomainController: " + sDomainController);

                    try
                    {
                        thisPipeline.Invoke();
                        iLogManager.Info(thisPipeline.Commands[0].CommandText);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ErrorText = "Error: " + ex.ToString();
                    }
                    // Check for errors in the pipeline and throw an exception if necessary.
                    if (thisPipeline.Error != null && thisPipeline.Error.Count > 0)
                    {
                        StringBuilder pipelineError = new StringBuilder();
                        pipelineError.AppendFormat("Error calling Add-MailboxPermission.");
                        foreach (object item in thisPipeline.Error.ReadToEnd())
                        {
                            pipelineError.AppendFormat("{0}\n", item.ToString());
                        }

                        ErrorText = ErrorText + "Error: " + pipelineError.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                }
            }

            finally
            {
                thisRunspace.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    if (ErrorText == "")
        return "no error occurred.";
    else
        return ErrorText;
```

Does Exchange allows impersonation of Exchange CMDlets that modifies ACL's or am I doing something wrong here..

Can anybody help me here, there is not much information about Exchange Powershell CMdlets with impersonation from ASPX page.

Comment: Some info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2008/09/25/howto-calling-exchange-powershell-from-an-impersonated-thead.aspx

Comment: Thank you for you information but I already knew about the page. Actually I got the impersonation idea from them.